# How to interpret detection limits

Tags: analytical-chemistry, spectroscopy, elements, spectrophotometry

I am learning about different analytical methods such as Atomic Absorption Spectrscopy and Atomic Emission Spectroscopy and I'm having a difficult time understand how to interpret the detection limits for the different methods. For example, for AES my book says **"detection limits when using an ICP are significantly better than those obtained with flame emission"** follow by the table below.

I understand that the detection limit shows the lowest quantity of an element that can be detected by the instrument. However, how do I choose which is the better instrument for an experiment? And why is "ICP significantly better than flame emission"? I would assume that the larger the detection limit, the better since you have a greater limit and thus a better chance of detecting the element. Is that not the correct way to think?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is NOT the correct way to think. The lower the detection limit of a method, the easier it is to detect the material. For example, from the data in the table, you would be able to detect 0.2 ug/ml of Ag using ICP, but only 2 ug/ml using flame emission. So, if your sample had less than 2 ug/ml and you were using flame emission, you would not be able to reliably detect the Ag in that sample. Make sense?

Comment: Oh okay, so if I didn't know the amount Ag in my sample I would choose ICP because it would allow to measure even the smallest amount of Ag in my sample but if I knew that my sample contained more than 2ug/ml then I could use flame emission.

Comment: Yes. That is the correct way to look at it.